# How can I create actions for a variable number of buttons?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton, actionevent

I'm creating a user interface for a game that I have to do as a class project, and needless to say I'm not experienced with Swing.

I did learn about actionevents and whatnot for simple button pushes, but in those cases I knew how many buttons would be on screen. Here, I need to create a board with an arbitrary number of tiles, which will be represented as buttons in Swing. I need to push a button and "move" my character from one tile to another, so I need to call a method on one tile object to remove the player from that tile, and then add it to another tile.

So my question is, given that the number of buttons is generated at runtime (and stored in a 2d array) how can I make an actionlistener that is able to distinguish between each unique button?

Answer (score 1):

Set all your buttons to the same handler:

```
ActionListener a = new ActionListener() {

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
       if (evt.getSource() == buttons[0][0]) {

       }
       // etc
       // common handling
   }
};

for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
  for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
    buttons[i][j].addActionListener(a);
```